# CAN i use python packages without installiaton?

Tags: python-3.x, package

My computer in the workplace is under corporate firewall and i cant install python packages.
Is there a way i can work with python and it's packages without the need to install them?

Comment: Do you have the option of downloading them manually?

Comment: i dont know how to downlad a package manually , can you add a link that explains how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to add the path to these packages to `sys.path`

for example:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(somedir, 'your_package'))
```

Comment: ok , i will try it, insted of 'somedir' i need to write my folder path?